# "Error restoring item version from history." while restoring version of content in custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, versions

I was trying to restore a version of content I am editing.

In the construct method of my administrator/components/com_joomprosubs/tables/subscription.php script, I added this following line:

```
JObserverMapper::addObserverClassToClass('JTableObserverContenthistory',
'JoomprosubsTableSubscription', array('typeAlias' => 'com_joomprosubs.subscription'));
```

This is based on what I have read in this link:
https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Content_History_in_your_Component

However, when I try to restore a version, an error is displayed:

> Error restoring item version from history.

The error is being returned due to the blank value of `typeAlias`. I don't know where I got it wrong. From the code that I added above, I have included the `typeAlias` with its corresponding value.

Has anybody tried adding versioning in their custom component?

Answer (score 2):

For now, I temporarily overridden the loadHistory function from the Base Class.

from there, i passed the alias as 'com_joomprosubs.subscription'. The restoring of version history is now working.

Is there a disadvantage in my resolution?